# Neither then nor catch is called

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

I am using the mssql module in Node.js.

I have the following where `date` is a column of smalldatetime:

```
function getData(date, callback) {
  var qs = "select * from T1 where date='2017-04-31'";
  new sql.Request().query(qs).then(function (result) {
        return callback(null, result);
      }).catch(function (err) {
        return callback(err);
      });
}
```

The value given in the `date` filter is invalid of type smalldatetime, but neither the `then` or `catch` block is called.  The code flow jumps to the end of the `getData` function and somewhere in the Node.js system it generated the following error:

> (node:11172) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 3): TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

The Node.js application didn't crash either, and so (this is a web application) the client is left with an opened connection.

Am I using the `then`/`catch` pattern correctly or is this likely to be a bug in the module?

Comment: Your `qs` string is unclosed. Also, what does your `callback` function look like? Are you possibly attempting to iterate over the results, even if called with an error?

Comment: I have fixed the typo in the post. I am also clearer about the problem now and have updated the question.

Comment: Without more information, the only (?) way that this could happen is if the `callback(err)` invocation in the `catch` handler threw an error. You can test this by adding another `catch`. Or you can turn on the devtools "stop on uncaught errors" checkbox and catch it in the act. Can you show us the `callback` code? Put some `console.log` statements at the beginning of both the `then` and `catch` handlers. Set some breakpoints. Step through the code. By the way, you seem to be mixing promises and callbacks in an odd fashion.

Comment: The error doesn't appear to be originating from the code in your question. I would presume the `TypeError` comes from your `callback` function. Without seeing that code, we're just guessing

Comment: The `then` block wasn't called, and hence the callback wasn't invoked.

Comment: Urgh, you are using the **same** `callback` in the `catch`! I would bet real money that you are attempting to iterate the `result` argument from that call in the `catch`

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The callback test for nullness in the first parameter.

Comment: That's odd, I can't see that test anywhere :/

Comment: I left out the wrapper function in the original question. Have put it in now. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Nope, still can't see it. I think you may have forgotten to post the **code for the callback function**

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the docs (assuming you are using https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql)...

```
sql.connect(config).then(function() {
    return sql.query('select * from mytable where id = ${value}')
}).then(result => {
    console.dir(result)
}).catch(err => {
    // ... error checks
})
```

So, the promise seems to be one level up from where you are using it (not on the `query`).

To use callbacks, it looks like you just do:

```
new sql.Request().query(qs, callback)
```

From what I'm reading, the promise on the `.query` only happens on INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE

Comment: Thanks. Does that mean it is not possible to trap a `select` error with this module?

Comment: The docs say that if `callback` is omitted from `query`, it returns a promise. I don't see anything about limiting that use to certain query types

Comment: In the documentation, under "Affected Rows", there is an example of the form `request.query(...).then(result => ...)`, so what the OP is trying may be OK.  As far as I can tell, the "if you're performing INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE in a query" condition applies to the specific example (affected rows), not to whether/not a promise is returned.